# Bound on Expected Value of Maximum of iid Geometric Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that we have $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ iid geometric random variables with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ satisfying $P(X_i=k)=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$ ($k$ can also be zero) and let $R=max{X_i}$

> Prove: 1. $P(R>log(n)+c)\le\frac{1}{2^c}$ for $c>0$ and $log$ is in base $2$

> 2. $E[R]\le \lceil{log(n)}\rceil+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{i}{2^i}$ and $log$ is in base $2$

The first part is easily seen using union bound.
Any help for the second part would be appreciated!

Comment: Incidentally, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\frac{i}{2^i} =2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that the expectation of a nonnegative discrete random variable $X$ can be written as $\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > i)$. Can you combine this with the first part of the question to finish the proof for part $2$?

Comment: Hi, This is what I've tried to do. But got stuck. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Write $\mathbb{E}(R - \log n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(R - \log n > i) - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(R - \log n < -i)$ (this is a general formula for the expectation of a finite-mean random variable). The second sum can of course be upper-bounded by zero. The probabilities in the first sum are upper-bounded by the first question. Then use the linearity of the expectation to finish.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this formula?

Comment: Google 'Expectation tail probability/sum'. One particular source could be 'Demystifying the Integrated Tail Probability Expectation Formula' by Ambrose Lo.

Comment: @bulgali Wikipedia source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties Search the "Properties" section for "Formulas in terms of CDF". They give the continuous case, which implies the discrete one. They cite Feller.